# Can Firebase Database be set up to host data for 3rd party client? (e.g., analytics service)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to set up Firebase to allow Auth/DB access into a *common/shared* database instance - where that instance is setup to be a centralized storage location for some 3rd party service?

For example, let's say there's an analytics service called StackOverflowAnalytics.com .. and so anyone who signs up for that service, can add tracking to their app with some secret user key.  And then all the tracking for that Key is pushed to the same Firebase DB instance.  And then the user can login via Firebase auth and the rules will restrict that they can only access the node for their Key.

---

I'm working on a 3rd party analytics client for Android - along the lines https://mint.splunk.com - where I would like to provide users a small Java/Android library they can add to their Android project, and this will help them track different data points while their app is running. The data is made accessible by saving it to the cloud from the device.

I am currently using Firebase, but it seems in order for the Firebase Auth & DB of a given Firebase instance to be accessible - the "specific app signing key" *(package name/etc combo)* needs to be set in the console for that Firebase instance.

It seems sharing across across unknown apps is not possible on Firebase. And that if I want to support something like that with Firebase *(and not have to go to another cloud storage option)*, then I need to set up some proxy REST client .. like in Java or PHP .. that can serve as a centralized access point to that Firebase instance.  Just wanted to check with other folks first in case this has been encountered and perhaps there are best practices already established around this particular case.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firebase client libraries are generally not meant to be repackaged for use in other libraries.  They're meant to be used at the app level.

A unique SHA-1 key is required on Android for Authentication to work with a particular app identified by package name. This requirement will definitely become a problem for you if you want this to work with arbitrary apps, since you would have to manually enter one for each app that wants to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible to do what you want without creating a proxy, as you mentioned. I assume that firebase has some app validation that make unfeasible to share the Auth/DB. 
Maybe a solution for you is to make a proxy too to access data:
"It looks like in order to access Firebase Analytics data, you export it to BigQuery. This is working for me and is automated."